# 交わり合わないような項目同士 translation

Tags: translation, formal-nouns, plural-suffixes

> **勉強とコミュニケーション能力。一見すると交わり合わないような項目同士。**

**交わる**: 1. to cross; to intersect; to join; to meet​, 2. to associate with; to mingle with; to consort with, 3. to have a sexual relationship; to copulate.

**合わない** --> **合う**: 1. to come together; to merge; to unite; to meet​, 2. to fit; to match; to suit; to agree with; to be correct​, 3. to be profitable; to be equitable​, 4. to do ... to each other; to do ... together​after the -masu stem of a verb (Auxiliary verb, Godan verb with u ending).

**同士**: 1. fellow; mutual; companion; comrade.

I was wondering if the following translation is proper:

"Our communication skills with our study. Those (kind of) subjects are not related/matched with each other at first glance."

I saw from many examples that it seems **同士** attached to a noun is not necessary to be translated specifically. Is it a correct interpretation?

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is fine. Did you notice that 同士 is actually "reflected" in your English? I mean:

> *subject**s***

同士 might be a tricky word, but not totally untranslatable to English if you bear with a disproportionately lengthy definition, that **X**同士 means *those each of who/which is (equally) a **X** to each other*. And this may explain why it is usually "not necessary to be translated specifically" in English.

> 恋人同士 "those each of who is the lover of each other" → *lovers*
>   ゲーム機同士の通信 "transmission between game consoles each of which is fellow of each other" → *transmission between (correspondent) game consoles*
>   仲間同士のけんか "quarrel of those each of who is a partner/friend of each other" → *quarrel among friends*
>   cf. 仲間たちのけんか *quarrel of my friends [had with another party]*